# Begin - End datapicker dates

Tags: jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a datapicker and i use it two times.

I have to disable previous dates if first datapicker is initialized and give user to chose modified datapicker.

So, i have this code :

```
<script>

         $(document).ready(function() {
        $( ".datapick" ).datepicker(
            {
                minDate: 0,
                dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',

            });
        });

</script>



<input type="text" name="start" class="datapick" placeholder="Starting date" class="datapick">


<input type="text" name="end" class="datapick" placeholder="End date" class="datapick">
```

I am using minDate to disable previous days, but i dont know if selected 24-12-2014, to disable all previous days.

I think you get me :))

Comment: why are you using class attributes twice in each input tag..?

Comment: just add the script without document ready state. please remove the $(document).ready(function() {}. and try it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this following. I hope it will work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function() {
        jQuery(".Start").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'mm-dd-yy', maxDate: 0 });
        jQuery(".End").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'mm-dd-yy', minDate: 0 });
    });
</script>

<input name="Start" class="Start" type="text" placeholder="Starting date">

<input name="End" class="End" type="text" placeholder="Ending date">
```

It may solve your problem :-)

Comment: @ dongou It is working fine for me.Could you please explain bit more.